# Rx Window, Join, GroupJoin?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have generated/tested two Observables to be combined for executing a single query.

A user can have multiple roles. Whenever their role id changes the data needs to be updated. But the data should only update if the query is active (there is some control that currently needs the data).

A role Id change can also happen when a query is suspended. When the query becomes active again the data should also load.

```
//Tuple has the Id of the current Role and the time that the Id updated
IObservable<Tuple<Guid, DateTime>> idUpdate

//Tuple has the state of the query (true=active or false=suspended)
//and the time the state of the query updated
IObservable<Tuple<bool, DateTime>> queryStateUpdate
```

I would like to create

```
//A hot observable that pushes true whenever the query should execute
IObservable<bool> execute
```

I broke it down into two cases that could be merged but I cannot figure out how to create the case observables.

- case a) the role Id updated & the last state was Active
- case b) the state updated to Active && this is the first active state since the role Id updated

I have looked through the videos, lee campbells site, the beginners TOC, etc but I can't seem to find a good example for this rx join. Any ideas on how to create the execute or case observables?

Comment: is there an ID (the Guid) that ties these two together? Like should queryStateUpdate be `IObservable<Tuple<Guid, bool, DateTime>>` or is there just one query state observable for all queries. I'm having trouble with the "id updated after it became suspended last" of Case B without something like that.

Comment: There is just one query state observable for all of the queries.

Comment: @AndersonImes - I agree with you. The question isn't particularly clear at the moment. Statements like "the Id updated after it became suspended last" and the signatures of the given observables both make me think that there are deeper requirements here that haven't clearly come through in this question.

Comment: I updated it for clarity. The Id is a user's role Id. A user can have multiple roles. Whenever their role changes the data needs to be updated. Although this should only happen whenever this query is active, (there is some control that currently needs the data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the problem as described - which is a little vague as I don't see what the actual id (`Guid`) is used for, nor the `DateTime` values - I've got the following query which appears to solve your problem:

```
IObservable<bool> execute =
    idUpdate
        .Publish(_idUpdate =>
            from qsu in queryStateUpdate
            select qsu.Item1
                ? _idUpdate.Select(x => true) 
                : Observable.Empty<bool>())
        .Switch();
```

I've tested this with the following `idUpdate` & `queryStateUpdate` observables.

```
var rnd = new Random();

IObservable<Tuple<Guid, DateTime>> idUpdate =
    Observable
        .Generate(
            0,
            n => n < 10000,
            n => n + 1,
            n => Tuple.Create(Guid.NewGuid(), DateTime.Now),
            n => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(rnd.NextDouble() * 0.1));

IObservable<Tuple<bool, DateTime>> queryStateUpdate =
    Observable
        .Generate(
            0,
            n => n < 100,
            n => n + 1,
            n => n % 2 == 0,
            n => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(rnd.NextDouble() * 2.0))
        .StartWith(true)
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .Select(b => Tuple.Create(b, DateTime.Now));
```

If you can provide some clarification around your problem I will probably be able to provide a better answer to suit your needs.

---

EDIT: Added the "replay(1)" behaviour required when the Id changes when inactive.

Please note that I have gotten rid of the need to have tuples with `DateTime`.

```
IObservable<Guid> idUpdate = ...
IObservable<bool> queryStateUpdate = ...

var replay = new ReplaySubject<Guid>(1);
var disposer = new SerialDisposable();
Func<bool, IObservable<bool>, IObservable<Guid>,
    IObservable<Guid>> getSwitch = (qsu, qsus, iu) =>
{
    if (qsu)
    {
        return replay.Merge(iu);
    }
    else
    {
        replay.Dispose();
        replay = new ReplaySubject<Guid>(1);
        disposer.Disposable = iu.TakeUntil(qsus).Subscribe(replay);
        return Observable.Empty<Guid>();
    }
};

var query =
    queryStateUpdate
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .Publish(qsus =>
            idUpdate
            .Publish(ius =>
                qsus
                    .Select(qsu =>
                        getSwitch(qsu, qsus, ius))))
        .Switch();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This works for Case A. Do you have any solution for Case B? (I tried to clarify the post).

Comment: Correction, this seems to execute on any id update regardless of the current state.

Comment: @jonperl - I tested this quite a bit and it definitely didn't produce values if the state is not active during my tests. Can you give me an example where it does?

Comment: I spent a fair bit of time trying to reproduce the issue and I realized there was a bug in my queryStateUpdate observable. Sorry yours did solve Case A.

Answer (score 1):

I read the question as saying that there is a stream of notifications `idUpdate`, which will be processed as long as `queryStateUpdate` is set. When `queryStateUpdate` isn't set, then the notifications should pause until `queryStateUpdate` is set again.

In which case the join operator is not going to solve your problem.

I would suggest that you need some form of cache while `queryStateUpdate` is unset, i.e.

```
List<Tuple<Guid,DateTime>> cache = new List<Tuple<Guid,DateTime>>();
Subject<Tuple<Guid,DateTime>> execute = new Subject<Tuple<Guid,DateTime>>();

idUpdate.Subscribe( x => {
    if (queryStateUpdate.Last().Item1) //might be missing something here with Last, you might need to copy the state out
        exeucte.OnNext(x);
    else
        cache.Add(x);
    });

queryStateUpdate.Subscribe(x=> {
    if (x.Item1)
    {
       //needs threadsafety
       foreach(var x in cache)
           execute.OnNext(x);
      cache.Clear();
    });
```

Comment: AlSki thanks for the help. The problem is that Last() blocks the thread and because I'm using Silverlight it doesn't work.

Comment: After thinking about it I think I might be onto something with CombineLatest and a Stack cache.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Enigmativity and AlSki. Using a cache I came up with the answer.

```
var execute = new Subject<Guid>();
var cache = new Stack<Guid>();
idUpdate.CombineLatest(queryStateUpdate, (id, qs) => new { id, qs }).Subscribe( anon =>
{
  var id = anon.id;
  var queryState = anon.qs;
  //The roleId updated after the queryState updated
  if (id.Item2 > queryState.Item2)
  {
      //If the queryState is active, call execute
      if (observationState.Item1)
      {
         cache.Clear();
         execute.OnNext(roleId.Item1);
         return;
      }
      //If the id updated and the state is suspended, cache it
      cache.Push(id.Item1);
  }
  //The queryState updated after the roleId
  else if (queryState.Item2 > roleId.Item2)
  {
     //If the queryState is active and a roleId update has been cached, call execute
     if (queryState.Item1 && cache.Count > 0)
     {
         execute.OnNext(cache.Pop());
         cache.Clear();
     }
  }});
```

Comment: This solution works except when your observables produce values at the same time (relative to the resolution of `DateTime`. Have a look at my update - I've solved it without the need for tuples with `DateTime`.